# Manually update curl on Raspbian stretch

Tags: shared-libraries, curl

Raspbian stretch only supports curl 7.52.1, but I need at least curl 7.56 for an application.

Is it save to manually update curl or is it likely to break the Linux distro?

Comment: the ubuntu image I am running on a pi4 has curl v 7.58.0 so there is certainly newer versions already compiled for ARM. If you are worried about something else breaking, I would save the current curl binary somewhere safe, add in the new one, and try it out. You can always move the old one back into place if there is a need to, but I suspect upgrading curl by a few minor version numbers is not going to break anything.

Comment: You'll need to download the source files, and compile them. Everything you need to do this is in the cURL documentation. I'd probably use the static library option (`./configure --disable-shared`) to keep things "clean" in case you decide to go back to the older version in the repository.

Comment: This question does not natively belong to Raspberry Pi. You should use the **Raspberry Pi OS**.. It has curl 7.64.0 available.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

- Upgrade "Raspbian stretch" to a more recent version of Raspberry OS.

or

- Uninstall curl `sudo apt remove curl` and then follow "[how to install curl and libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)" and follow the instructions from the **UNIX** section.

Comment: Uninstalling `curl` may break (or force remove) other packages that depend on it.

Comment: That is the case with all packages that has dependencies.

Comment: Yes, and removing such packages is generally a bad idea.